# Median for sparse matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, median

What is the best way to obtain the median (along the row and column) of a sparse.csr_matrix matrix in python?

PS: The [webpage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) doesnt have any function of median

Comment: Con it it to dense.

Comment: Sorry about my cryptic comment from the phone.  A sparse matrix is good for operations that can be expressed as a matrix operation.  It even uses it for row sums and indexing.  But iteration on rows is slow.  If you must use a sparse format, convert your matrix to `lil` and show us how you'd find the median of each row list.

Comment: `np.median(M.A, axis=0)` for a reasonably sparse matrix is likely to be all 0s.  That is, it most of the elements in a row are 0, the middle one (in a sorted list) probably will be 0.

Comment: I think the last comment is quite important: if the median is not 0; one should think about the sparsity-ratio: do i really want to use sparse-mats? (not that it would be impossible to speed up median-calculation on a sparse-vector obtained from a sparse-matrix complexity-wise; but probably only paying off for huge dimensions in practice)

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the median of the column entries of a sparse matrix, sklearn has an implementation for CSC matrices

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.py#L441

As mentioned in the comments, median of nnz elements makes more sense here, since for a sufficient sparse matrix row/column median is zero.